# Downloading file from server PHP - File is slightly off

Tags: php, html

I hope this is a simple and quick fix. I have looked on here already to learn how to force download a file from the server. Here is what I am using below:

```
<?php
// Sending the file - a pdf in this case
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');

// Specify what the  file will be called
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="1234.txt"');

// And specify where it is coming from 
readfile('C:\test\1234.txt');
?>
```

It should be pretty self explanatory but I have a text file saved at C:\test\1234.txt.

I link to my php file (that has the above code) which is called download.php using this from the HTML page:

```
<a href="/download.php" title="Download This PDF">Download This File!</a>
```

---

OK now the problem.. My original text file is this:

```
test
```

but when I download the file, the result is a carriage return above:

```
_
test
```

The problem isn't huge with the text file, but because of this issue, all other files downloaded are corrupt and I believe this is why. I am hoping that someone has a solution to this that is pretty simple.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A `.txt` file and an `.exe` and PDF `title="Download This PDF"`; I for one am baffled.

Comment: The problem is, more than likely, that you're loading a .exe file as your file to download, telling the browser it's a text file, and then going from there. PS: Just noticed the update. So were you or were you not doing this with an exe file as opposed to text?

Comment: Sorry guys, that was a typo when typing this up. I updated it now. It is actually .txt in both cases

Comment: Have you thought about just passing the filename into file_get_contents instead of using readfile, which uses the output stream? Do you plan on doing anymore with this other than allowing the download of text files?

Comment: What mechanism is constructing the actual PDF file?  Everything in the code you've shown only references a `txt` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try removing the PHP closing tag.  Note this quote from php.net

> If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing
>   tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new
>   lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted
>   effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no
>   intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the
>   script.

Perhaps that's where you're getting the extra carriage return.

Comment: I think that's a valid scenario.

Comment: Tried that. Still results in the carriage return :/

Comment: Actually... weirdly enough when I deleted the "php" tag and then readded it, the resulting file was good. No idea why but this worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could have been some extra whitespace. readfile sets up output buffering, and if you've got weird space in a file that is using buffering you can end up with unexpected results like this as the file is packaged to be sent down the pipes